# Using a image file in a project as a resource

Tags: c#, .net, resources

I need to use an image that is in the res folder inside the project, like an resource but during the compilation of the project I get an exception like "System.IO.IOException" with the description "The resource "res/rook.png" cannot be found.".

```
chessField = new ChessField();
chessField.fillField();
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
  Border border = new Border();
  border.Background = i % 2 == 0 ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black;
  Image chessPiece = new Image();
  string pngFileName;
  if (chessField.Field[i / 8, i % 8] != null) 
  {
    pngFileName = chessField.Field[i / 8, i % 8].pieceType.ToString().ToLower();
    chessPiece.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/ChessWPF;component/res/{pngFileName}.png",
        UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
  }
  border.Child = chessPiece;
  xamlField.Children.Add(border);
}
```

An exception occurs on the line `new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/ChessWPF;component/res/{pngFileName}.png"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to open the properties of png files and mark them as a resource in the Build Action field.